# Removal of hyperlink on multimedia/binary component unpublish

Tags: multimedia, unpublishing

Currently Dynamic component unpublishing manages the hyperlink on the website page by removing the hyperlink leaving out the as plain text whereas in case of binary/multimedia component unpublishing the hyperlink remains on the webpage and redirects to 404 page.
We want to include similar functionality for binary links i.e hyperlink to be removed, when the linked binary is unpublished. Also, the hyperlink needs to be reactivated then the binary is republished.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, binary links are handled very differently from component links for a very basic reason: component links "live" on pages, while binary links have their own URL. In other words, at publish time it's nearly impossible to determine the URL for a regular component (it could be in many different pages, link priority needs to be calculated, etc), while binaries already have a pre-defined URL.

I do not think you can achieve this without custom code, you would need to create some logic yourself that checks if the binary is published while rendering the pages & links. Maybe you can try treating binary links as "regular" component links, but I can't tell without some testing.

Comment: @puf had a good explanation on TridionWorld years back for how typical binary "publishing" wasn't the same as other content. With templating, binaries are added to packages and removed when the count of items linking to them gets to zero in Content Delivery. However, with a Component Template we can publish and unpublish binaries. Anyways, I also think binaries could be handled with the [BinarlyLink tcdl tag](https://docs.rws.com/1099765/106602/tridion-sites-10-main-documentation/binarylink). Alternatively, tcdl ComponentLink would need to have Binaries _on_ Pages as Component Presentations.